Geolocalizacion en Python, funciona a veces
estoy empezando a programar en python, y todavia no termino de entender cierto conceptos.
He desarrollado un pequeño script para obtener las coordenadas gps de una direccion que paso a traves de parametros desde consola en linux. EL problema que tengo, es que funciona a veces.
Mis conocimientos de python son practicamente nulos, y no soy capaz de averiguar porque hace eso.
Este es el codigo que uso(disculpad cualquier error de sintaxis o de estructura):
#libreria para pasarle parametros desde consola
from sys import argv
#libreria para geolocalizar direcciones
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

import time
import math

#creamos el metodo que buscara las coordenadas gps con la
#direccion enviada por parametros desde consola
def obtener_coordenadas(direccion):
    #creamos el objeto nominatim
    geo = Nominatim(user_agent="myGeocoder")
    try:
       #obtenemos la geolocalizacion de la direccion y
       #restringiendo el pais a SPAIN
        print(direccion)
        ubicacion = geo.geocode(direccion,country_codes='es',timeout=5)
        #guardamos la latitud y la longitud
        if ubicacion:
            print("Latitud:" + str(ubicacion.latitude) + "," + "Longitud" + str(ubicacion.longitude))
        else:
            return None, None
    #en caso  de error devolvemos mensaje
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: Direccion no Geolocalizada")
        return None, None

def main():
    #definimos el script y el parametro que vamos a pasar como argumento
    #en este caso direccion
    script = argv
    direccion = argv[1]
    #llamamos al metodo que geolocalizara la direccion pasandole como
    #parametro la direccion
    obtener_coordenadas(direccion)

Me desconcierta que al hacer la llamado pasandole una direccion, hay veces que devuelve correctamente las coordenadas y otras veces, pasandole la misma direccion, devuelve el error de la geolocalizacion.
Agradeceria enormemente que ayudarias a este pobre novato y mis disculpas si no esta correctamente formulada la pregunta, o el codigo.
Gracias.

¿Haz verificado si el sitio tiene restricciones de uso, cómo número de consultas por hora/día?

Hola Candid, gracias  por responder. Segun la informacion que he encontrado, no tiene limites de consultas diarias. Igualmente, solo estoy haciendo pruebas con consultas individuales, para verificar que el script funciona.

Hola Jose, bienvenido a [es.so]. Si no lo has intentado ya, yo empezaría por quitar el try-except o al menos imprimir la excepción (e) en el except. Es posible que la excepción y su traza den una pista de la razón del fallo, bien sea del lado del servicio o de tu cliente.

Hola @FJSevilla, gracias por la aclaracion. Probare como dices, a ver si la excepcion me  indica porque a  veces funciona y otras no, usando la misma direccion.

Da un error, sin indicar exactamente cuál es el mensaje de error, nos deja en blanco. Incluye siempre los mensajes de error completos en tus preguntas.

Totalmente cierto @jachguate, mis disculpas, estoy empezando en  python y todavia no controlo las formas, ya me indicaron que añadiese la impresion de la  excepcion y ya vi que era por la codificacion. Gracias por la ayuda.

@Jose, si lograste resolver tu problema, te aliento a responder a tu pregunta. No olvides responder con una explicación como si quien pregunta fuese otra persona, pues eso ayudará a futuros navegantes. Para inspirarte, lee [answer]. Un saludo.

He añadido tal como me indico @FJSevilla,la impresion del  error.
#en caso  de error devolvemos mensaje
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: Direccion no Geolocalizada")
        #mostramos el texto del error que devuelve pyton
        print("Error:,e)
        return None, None

En mi caso, me estada devolviendo este error:
'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udca5' in position 4: surrogates not allowed
El problema me lo estaba generando la distribucion de teclado de mi consola linux, al  escribir texto con Ñ no lo enviaba correctamente.
